# Why is Google Appengine so slow connecting to CloudSQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am seeing a drastic difference in latency between development and production when connecting to a CloudSQL backend, much more so than I would expect.

I ran a test where:

1. I fetched 125, 250, 500, 1000 and 2000 rows (row size approximately 30bytes)
2. I fetched each row size 20 times, to get a good sampling of the time

The test was run in three environments:

1. Hosted appengine
2. Development mode locally, but connecting to CloudSQL via static IP
3. Development mode locally and connecting to a local VM running MySQL

Here you can see the results:
[image: Graph of results]

Now I would expect some speed fluctuations on the order of 50ms-200ms but 3-4 *seconds* seems a bit high.

I'm new to appengine, so any newb mistakes that might be causing this? Or other suggestions? I ran a profiler on my code in appengine and there is a call to _apiProxy.Event "wait" that eats up at least 500ms, but didn't go up more than 750ms, other than that, there was any long running calls. A number of shorter running calls that eventually add up of course, but it's not like I have a loop that needs to be tuned or anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you connecting to Cloud SQL in prod? Are you using the native drivers? The old, deprecated, way to connect was slow (particularly in Python). :-(

The round-trip-time for a 'SELECT 1' on an established connection should be under 2ms.

Comment: I am connecting using sqlalchemy, which uses mysqldb under the hood, as outlined here http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.gaerdbms . I will write a test that does just a "SELECT 1" and see how long that takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, check the connectivity path you are using: are you [connecting via the latest documented method](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/)? Cloud SQL used to have a connectivity path which is slower and is now deprecated, but still functioning, so you could be accessing via that.

Second, is the App Engine app and Cloud SQL instance in the same location? Check that the "Preferred Location" in your Cloud SQL settings are set to follow the app engine app you are connecting to.

As a last possibility, which seems unlikely given that you have data connecting locally, make sure you are reusing database connections, making new ones can be expensive. If there was some reason why your app is reusing connections locally but making new ones on the App Engine side, that could create this behavior. But like I said, this one seems unlikely.

Comment: I am connecting using SqlAlchemy, which uses mysqldb under the hood, as outlined here http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.gaerdbms. That's a good thought though that the connection is what's wrong.

In the local/cloudsql test, I was connecting straight to the static IP, but in production I'm using the instancename method. I'll try pointing to the IP and see if that makes a difference.

Also, I am using the Preferred Location option. Do you have an example of the deprecated method? So I can verify that?

Comment: Looking into the source, sqlalchemy is using this (https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/rdbms_mysqldb.py?r=277) under the hood, which looks like the example here (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/)

Comment: In App Engine prod you will get better performance using the /cloudsql/ unix socket. If you really want IP connectivity in App Engine prod you can use the Connector/Python (currently, MySQLdb doesn't work).

Comment: @RazvanMusaloiu-E. I don't really want IP connectivity. I'm going to write up a quick test that doesn't use SqlAlchemy and see if that makes a difference, because I'm having trouble determining what SqlAlchemy is using.

Comment: Alright, I made a test that bypassed sqlalchemy and just connected as seen in the docs. My query returns, without json encoding, in 250ms. Which is about 3.5s faster than before. So it's clearly something wrong with the way sqlalchemy is connecting. Thanks for the help guys!