# Very slow connection opening

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to use Cloud SQL gen2, but am having quite long times (1-2s) often to just open the connection. I have a D1 gen2 instance, with a cpu load smaller than 7% and less than 6 connection on the SQL server. The actual sql calls are quite fast after opening the connection. The gen1 D1 instance before seemed faster at this.
Is there any way to make the connection opening faster? This is from app engine, java, using the DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl) call.

Update:
To be more precise, Cloud SQL gen2 in europe-west1 accessed from appengine java in europe-west

Update:
I now also tried with 2 and 4 core db servers, does not change anything in connection opening times (always with SSD), still often more than 1s.

Update, I did find this here:
[Why is Google Appengine so slow connecting to CloudSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274037/why-is-google-appengine-so-slow-connecting-to-cloudsql?rq=1) but that does not really help.

Comment: I also saw this: https://github.com/kennberg/appengine-java-connection-pool , but it seems a bit strange to do some kind of connection pooling if the official sample code does not do it.

Comment: Also, this type of connection pooling probably does not help because I use only one single connection for the whole of the request.

Comment: Why is my question down voted? Is there anything else I could mention? I did read about the 12 connection / instance limit and 250 / SQL limit, but with max 6 open connections on the server this should really not be the problem. Also, D1 with less than 7% load seems not likely to be overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Using github.com/kennberg/appengine-java-connection-pool makes a huge difference. It does not really explain why opening a connection takes 1-2s, but makes the problem manageable in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

We are experiencing the same problem!

Just played around with different types of app engine instances and cloud sql instances.. but the time to open a connection is always between **400-600ms**.
The requests (SELECT queries) itself are processed in **2-3 ms**

Did you make any progress with this problem?

Comment: No, we were not able to solve the problem itself. But if you look at my answer above, we were able to mitigate it with this. Although it will not work well for all cases probably.

Comment: Okay, so you use the connection pool (github.com/kennberg/appengine-java-connection-pool) to solve the connection time problem? What about the maximum Socket time of 60 sec? After that time the app engine will close the open socket connection..

Comment: Somehow that does not seem to be the case, as (in the logs) I can see that a new connection is only initiated sporadically, sometimes with 3h in between. There is always more than 1 request per second to the db.